# Configuring CodeBlocks to read shapefile using GDAL library in c++ in console application

Tags: gdal, windows-10

I am using CodeBlocks on Windows10 to load vector data using console application in c++ using GDAL/OGR library,  settings are set to as follows:

```
compiler settings/
    search directories/
        compiler/
            C:\GDAL\bld\include (contains .h files)
        linker/
            C:\\GDAL\bld\lib(contains .lib files)
project build options/
    linker settings/
        C:\GDAL\bld\lib\gdal_i.lib
    search directories/
        [same as in compiler settings]
```

still I am getting ‘undefined reference to’ errors..

How to solve it? Is there any other way for setting a proper configuration?